# Newbie questions about XMRig

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, privacy

1. Can one Monero wallet be used to receive results from XMRig installed on 20  (or more) computers?
2. Should the json file on each computer contain the same data?
3. May I use XMRig in Whonix?
4. What the best way to use XMRig anonymously?

Comment: anonymous from whom? with what access level(from someone who monitors only your trafic or from the pool's server or from someone who has access to your hardwares)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you have to place your xmr address in the config, along with the pool address you chose.
2. Not necessarily, you could just keep the same address and pool, but other settings depends on your mining hardware
3. Yes, why not? it's just another debian based OS. you can edit the Cmake file to deal with your OS.
4. You could probably use it with tor or i2p by redirecting the traffic to it.